# the system settings icon disappeard, how to restore it?

Tags: icons, desktop-environments, system-settings

The systems settings icon, i.e., the gear wheel in the screenshot [here](http://tinypic.com/r/k0ikhx/8) with yellow circle suddenly disappeared. I have no more information to offer because it just suddenly disappeared. How to restore it? You can just tell me its name or command line instruction to restore it, I know I can drag and drop it. I just don't know its name, I tried control panel or system settings, but couldn't find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click on the top-left icon ("the dash")

   [image: Dash icon]
2. Type `System Settings`
3. Click the sole remaining icon:

   [image: System settings icon]
4. and it'll re-appear!
5. To "lock" it permanently to the "launcher" again,

   1. Right click its icon on the launcher
   2. Click <kbd>Lock to Launcher</kbd>.

**Alternatively**, click the tiny gears icon in the top right of the screen, and then choose <kbd>System Settings</kbd> and stop worrying that the other icon is gone!  ;-)

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as your and my reputation will go up...

Comment: I followed that guy's answer but now there is nothing on my desktop. I don't know how to enter command-line, I don't even know how to shutdown the machine. Please help me restore to everything before. There is too many data in the ubuntu, I can't reinstall the whole ubuntu. Please help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Ctrl][Alt][T] to enter command line. Your simple problem just became a complicated problem... @edward-torvalds ?

Comment: Thank you Fabby. The Ctrl-Alt-T give the terminal back to me, and I can reboot it now, but how to restore the left panel and the annoying ugly blue "login:" window ...

Comment: I don't know.  What Edward gave you was the re-installation instructions for the desktop, so it should have worked too, but the state your system is in now, I don't have enough experience to help you.

Comment: I advise you to post a new question.