# How to remove the ugly blue log in?

Tags: users, login-screen

Due to following [some guy's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563106/the-system-settings-icon-disappeard-how-to-restore-it), now when I tried to log into the ubuntu, I was given an ugly blue login window:

[image: blue login]

I thought I can get rid of it by setting automatic login and found some hints on it, but the "unlock" button in the User Account is greyed so I can not set Automatic Login to "ON", as shown by this picture:

[image: disabled unlock]

So what should I do to remove the ugly blue log in? Thanks a lot.

A follow-up: I used command "sudo gnome-control-center user-accounts" to turn on the Automatic Login option and restart. But still see the ugly blue login window.

Comment: With the image you have attached, I can identify it as Lxdm. But not sure whether you have installed it as a Log in theme or entire GUI for Ubuntu.

Comment: @vembutech: I did install lxde on my ubuntu, but I'm not sure if this ugly blue login UI is the lxde because it never works in the remote desktop. I will remove it to see if it will disappear.

Comment: @vembutech: I think I have removed lxde and xrdp using apt-get purge. But the same thing comes out again.

Comment: Try to log out and check whether you get the default Ubuntu log in screen with "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" in bottom left.

Comment: I can not log out in regular way because the icons at the top-right corner in the top bar disappears. So I have to use "gnome-session-quit" in command line to log out. After that, I immediately come to this ugly blue login, instead of the familiar ubuntu login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like lxdm, the display manager LXDE uses. I gathered from the comments that you installed LXDE, and because of that lxdm was installed as well. To reset the display manager back to lightDM (Ubuntu's default) you can run this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Select "ok" and then "lightdm". Reboot.

Alternatively removing lxdm would probably work too (I haven't tested this though):

```
sudo apt-get remove lxdm
```

Reboot.